# Form inputs not retrievable using bodyParser and Router()

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I am trying to create a registration form which will pass data to the registration route. However, I am having trouble retrieve the form inputs in registration route. Please advice how to retrieve the form data inside the api.js file. I have tried using POSTMAN to send data to the /api/registration endpoint which did create a user in the database. When I actually use the html form to register, it failed.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <form action="/api/register" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email">
        <input name="password" type="password"  placeholder="Password">
        <input name="passwordConf" type="password"  placeholder="Confirm Password">
        <input type="submit" value="Register">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Index.js**

```
    //----setting up modules
const express = require('express');
const hbs = require('hbs');
const path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://localhost/test');


//----define port connection on various environmentls
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

//----createing express app
var app = express();

// parse incoming requests
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//----use express middle-ware to utitlize public folder
// app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'public'));
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
//see the first argument in above line it assigns which directory path is used to access the public file through URL


//----initializing handlebars as express view engine
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

//----define handlebars partials and helpers 
hbs.registerPartials(__dirname + '/views/partials');
//----define helper to get current year
hbs.registerHelper('getDate', ()=>{
    return new Date().getFullYear();
});

//----define routes
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('home.hbs')
})

// include routes
app.use('/api', require('./routes/api'));
app.use('/', require('./routes/page'));

//----connecting to port
app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log(`success connection to port ${port}`);
})
```

**Api.js Route**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var {User} = require('./../models/user');
var {authenticate} = require('./../middleware/authenticate');
var _ = require('lodash');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json()
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })


router.post('/register',function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    });
module.exports = router;
```

**pages.js**

```
    var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/register', function (req, res) {
    res.render('register.hbs', {title:"REGISTER"} )
})

router.get('/login', function (req, res) {
    res.render('login.hbs', {title:"LOGIN"} )
})

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: The code looks like it should work. You have no code that actually does the registration, just console.log, so submitting the form means it won't register anyone

Comment: @apscience, No. I actually have the code for registration but I have replaced it with console.log(req.body);. I am still trying to figure out why it is not retrieving the form data

Comment: i believe arises from the fact you have method="/api/register" and then you call the router as router.post('/register') . They dont match

Comment: @AmirHosseinRd, I have changed the form action to "/api/register" and endpoint to "/api/register" as well now. But it still does not work

Comment: do u get 'cannot get /api/register' error?

Comment: Can you tell us the error you get ? Either the one displaying on the browser or when you go to console.

Comment: @AmirHosseinRd yes. I do get that error on my browser.

Comment: Are you able to see the form ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169556/discussion-between-amirhossein-rd-and-applepie).

Comment: I see `app.use(bodyParser.json())` but not `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded())`. Since you're not posting JSON, you'll need the default form handler. Also, why is your form `enctype` _"multipart/form-data"_? You aren't posting any files

Comment: Thank you, @Phil. I have managed to make this work by combining your suggestions with AmirHossein Rd his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my recommendation:

Create a file called routes.js and include ALL your routes there and import it.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('home.hbs')
})

router.get('/api/register', function (req, res) {
    res.render('register.hbs', {title:"REGISTER"} )
})

router.post('/api/register',function (req, res) {
    //do your post logic here
    console.log(req.body);
    });

router.get('/login', function (req, res) {
    res.render('login.hbs', {title:"LOGIN"} )
})

module.exports = router;
```

in your Index.js :

```
//Make sure the route is correct

app.use('/', require('/routes/routes.js'));
```

Doing this, I expect the error to be solved,
Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! This actually works if I include app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded()) in index.js and remove enctype from my registration form